# Mule 4 debug how to maintain history of debug statements in studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

In Mule 4 anypoint studio when I am debugging an application , many a times I need to view the payload in json format , so while in debug view I go here :
[Evaluate Dataweave expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMLTd.png)

Here everytime I have to manually paste the below dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

However it is quite a pain to everytime either type the above code or copy paste it ...
Is there a way to make studio maintain history ? In fact there is a dropdown `Script History` which does not seem to be populated .

When I compare this against Mule 3 we do have a history of past commands .
Any way to ensure studio for mule 4 we can have history maintained ?

Comment: Which release of Studio 7 are you using?

Comment: the version of studio 7 is 7.13

Comment: Try first testing in Studio 7.15, the latest release at this time.

Comment: If this is a feature that Studio 7 doesn't implement you should ask MuleSoft to implement it.